# JSF 2.0, URL redirection to external website, after which some operation needs to be done on the original window

Tags: jsf, redirect

I am building a JSF 2.0 application. Basically this is the flow :

1. Perform some steps (pre conditions)
2. Redirect to external server based on results of preconditions
3. Perform some post redirection steps (update status flags etc)

The question I have is, once I do a redirection to an external server, how do I get the post redirection code to execute ? The control will be totally out of my application right ?

All the 3 steps above happen on clicking a command button , and my code is under doPost()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using standard Java EE stack, just put [`@Asynchronous`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html) on the EJB service method you're invoking after redirect. It'll run in a separate thread and allowing the current thread to continue directly (and thus to return from action method directly without blocking).

E.g.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    @EJB
    private SomeService someService;

    public void doPost() throws IOException { // Strange name for a JSF command button action btw, confuses with a standard HttpServlet method.
        // ... Preprocessing ...

        externalContext.redirect(externalURL);

        someService.doSomethingAsynchronously();
    }

    // ...
}
```

with

```
@Stateless
public class SomeService {

    @Asynchronous
    public void doSomethingAsynchronously() {
        // ... Update stuff ...
    }

    // ...
}
```